# Что делает программа. Битовые операции

Tags: c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
 
int f (int x){
 
    unsigned mask = 0x1;
    // Постановка 0x перед числом позволяет вводить шестнадцатеричные числа.
 
    return (x & mask); // Битовое И (&)
  
}
int main () {
 
    int N = 19;
 
    printf ("The result is %d\n",f(N)); // 19
    printf ("The result is %d\n",f(2 * N + 1)); // 39
    printf ("The result is %d\n",f(2 * N)); // 38
    return 0;
}
```

**Вывод:**

```
The result is 1
The result is 1
The result is 0
```

Есть такая программа, надо разгадать что она делает. Тут используются битовые операции, я знаю что битовое И (&) сравнивает последовательно разряд за разрядом два операнда. Для каждого разряда результат равен 1, тогда и только тогда, когда оба соответствующих разряда операндов равны 1.

Но не могу понять конкретно что эта программа делает и как. Надеюсь на вашу помощь!

Comment: Возвращает младший бит (определяет четность) числа

Comment: @avp, спасибо, а как вы поняли что именно младший бит а не старший например?

Comment: `(1 << 0)` это 1 (значение mask). Биты нумеруются с 0. Таким образм это младший бит. Кстати, старший определяет знак числа (если тип переменно signed (например, int)). А вообще, интересно, своим вопросом (в комментарии) вы меня (секунд на несколько) прямо в тупик поставили, как это объянснять. Наверное я так давно программирую, что мне показалось, что я знал это всегда

Comment: @avp, спасибо большое, только не понимаю почему если биты нумеруются с 0 то 1 это младший бит? а не 0

Comment: и почему младший бит определяет четность числа

Comment: В выражении `1 << 0` 1 это значение бита, а 0 его номер. Вообще, лучше почитайте что-нибудь о представлении чисел в компьютере. Информации в сети просто море, наверное где-то вы найдете понятные слова

Comment: @avp, спасибо!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Производит битовое сравнение И

Например:

```
int a = 1;  // Биты : 00000001
int b = 5;  // Биты : 00000101

int c =
    a & b; // Равно : 00000001   == 1
```

Где нижний бит накладывается на верхний

```
1 и 1 = 1
0 и 0 = 0
1 и 0 = 0
```

Дополнительную информацию можно найти на YT.

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZuMlrKl19Hw

Comment: Только одно замечание - вряд ли эту операцию можно назвать сравнением?